# Find the maximum convex area

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

My question is very similar to [Plow's Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279478/maximum-circle-inside-a-non-convex-polygon); but with this difference:

How can I find the maximum convex area that can fit inside a non-convex region?

For an example, consider this non-convex region :
[image]

Any ideas or solution would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I changed "concave region" to non-convex.  If you have a clearer notion of what regions you are interested in (beyond polygons), e.g. without holes, it would improve the Question to state those assumptions.  That said, this has the germ of an interesting optimization challenge.

Comment: Dear @hardmath; I would like to consider regions which have holes.

Comment: Since a convex subregion must be disjoint from "holes", perhaps tackling the problem without holes (simply connected regions) would be a good start, and then a method of reducing a problem involving holes to one without holes.

Comment: yes, you're right.But the problem with considering non-convex regions without holes was solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943482/find-the-maximum-convex-area

Comment: I'm doubtful that the Answer you link to really maximizes over convex regions.  Circle inversion maps circles to circles (or straight lines), so it's plausible that the method there finds a maximum area *disk*, but this is generally smaller than the maximum area convex subset.  For example, consider the outline of [the Star of David figure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_of_David) where the maximum convex subregion would be an equilateral triangle (exceeding the area of a circle through the six "inside" vertices).

Comment: @hardmath Your example makes me wonder! You're right: http://s4.picofile.com/file/7870104294/Capture1.png

Comment: Identify every boundary element (curve segment, point) with negative curvature (i.e. bent towards the inside). For each of these, you want to find a line which touches the boundary, and which defines a half plane on the inside-pointing side of the line. Then your result would be the intersection of all these half planes with the original shape. There should be finitely many different combinatorics arising from different choices for these lines, and for each of them it should be possible to find an optimal set of lines. Still a lot of work, and won't handle holes, but might get you started.

Comment: @MvG your approach does not give the optimal solution. for an example consider the outline of "the Star of David figure" and do your procedure for that.(The maximum convex sub-region would be an equilateral triangle)

Comment: In the Star of David case, you have six single points with negative curvature. Along each of them you want to find a line. The area is maximized if you choose these lines such that they coincide with edges of the star. More precisely, they should alternatingly coincide with the incoming and the outgoing edge in a yclic traversal. In this case, the six lines would form pairs of identical lines, which in turn form the equilateral triangle of the optimal solution. Seems to be well within the scope of my procedure, though the details of finding combinations and optimizing lines are rather sketchy.

Comment: I have an impression that this is a very difficult problem. If the region is described as polygons with $n$ vertices, I tend to think the amount of time to find the optimal solution is not polynomial in $n$. If you are ok with the largest circle, you can use the edge Voronoi diagram (medial axes). If you are ok with the largest axis-aligned square, you can use the $L_1$ edge Voronoi diagram. This is all I can think about now. Oh, and if you want to try ellipses instead of circles, or parallelograms instead of squares, apply a linear transformation to the input region first.

Comment: Dear @MvG Although your described approach to be effective in the hexagram; but I think there is sth wrong with that. In further details I think the "intersection" operator doesn't work with all cases. For an example please consider the non-convex region shown above. You can conclude that the intersection of all half planes with the original shape is smaller than the region which obtain with visual sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer deals only with the simple case, without holes or self-intersections.

Take the bounday, and identify elements which are not locally convex. I call a point on the boundary locally convex if there exists a disk of radius $\epsilon$ around the point which, when intersected with the shape, will yield a convex intersection. In the case of polygons, the non-convex boundary elements will be the vertices with interior angle exceeding $\pi$. In the case of a smooth curve, the non-convex boundary elements will be those parts of the curve where the curvature bends inwards, with two inflection points as the end points of the non-convex element.

For each such non-convex element you have to find one line which is tangent to the boundary element in question. That line defines a half plane pointing inwards from the boundary. The intersection of all these half planes with the original shape will be a convex shape.

So now your task is that of finding suitable lines. You can split that task in two parts. In a combinatoric step, you can investigate which combinatorics could possibly occur. Basically you check which lines might intersect within the shape, and which outside, and you iterate over all possible combinations that can occur this way. In the next step, you try to optimize the area for a given combinatorics, using non-linear optimization. I'm not sure whether determining the combinatorics up front will be enough to make this optimization problem convex, but I expect this to be the case for many practical applications at least.

To illustrate my ideas, here is the result when applied to your example shape:

[image: Algorithm applied to example shape]

This was done using a polygonal approximation of your shape with 269 vertices. I didn't implement the combinatorics preprocessing, but instead tried all possible line combinations in a rather brute-force approach. Basically I had four nested loops, one for each non-convex boundary element (drawn in red). For each I took all possible combinations of two consecutive polygonal vertices to define a line, and in the innermost loop I computed the resulting area. The blue lines were the optimal solution, resulting in the green convex shape.

I wrote a bit more on this implementation in [my answer to the corresponding Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17967201/1468366).

Comment: Hmm... For the straight line parts of your constructed area, it looks like the point of contacts with the original boundary coincide with the mid points of corresponding line segment.